# Selenium - How to click on a-tag

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to python, webscraping and selenium- so my question might be very basic. I was following a lot of advice to similar questions here, but that did not help with my problem

The url I am opening with selenium contains a button "sign in". The corresponding html line looks like this:

```
<a class="o-buttons o-buttons--big" role="button" href="https://accounts.ft.com/login?location=https%3A%2F%2Fftalphaville.ft.com%2F2012%2F07%2F27%2F1098471%2Fwhat-is-the-ecb-going-to-do-next%2F" data-trackable="sign-in">or sign in</a>
```

and the x-path is

```
html/body/section/div/div/div[1]/div/a[2]
```

Among others, I was trying to use

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/u[data-trackable='sign-in')]")
button.click()
```

but it did not work- can anybody help me out?

Comment: that is actually correct syntax, what error are you getting?
Can you paste html source of the website?

Comment: Sorry, I had the html and the x-path in the question but it is not showing here

Comment: Hope it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is not correct:
`button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-trackable='sign-in']")
button.click()`

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot! [Cannot upvote b/c of too low reputation here]

Comment: this is right, was just about to update my answer. Anyways kudos